# Laravel - php artisan make:model Project Doesnt Work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I need to use this command to create a Model.

And when I do that:

```
php artisan make:model Project
```

I recieve

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.
```

So, in the tutorial that i'm following the guy uses this to make a model.

What Should I Do?

So, I discover i'm using laravel 4 and this command doenst exist there.

How Can I build a Model without this make command?

Comment: type in `php artisan` and you can see all the commands. Its possible you are missing a package or something

Comment: `make:model` is from Laravel 5. The command doesn't exist in Laravel 4

Comment: @lukasgeiter why not post that as an answer?

Comment: i'm using Laravel 4.

Comment: So @Styphon How can I build this Model?

Comment: @EricTeixeira By right clicking on your model folder and selecting New File.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `make:model` command is new to Laravel 5 so won't be available to you in 4.

To make a model you can simply create a new file in your models folder with the following code

```
class MyModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

    // Code here

}
```

There is a package available from Jeffrey Way (who created Laracasts) that has some commands that will generate many things for you, including models, which I found really useful when developing with 4. https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Answer (score 1):

To generate Models with artisan in laravel 4 you need install [JeffreyWay way's](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) package.
It has amazing generators for your laravel 4 app